# License requirements for custom app

Tags: licenses, developer

I would like to develop an app (with custom objects and tabs) and license it to some users. These users need each their own separate data and sometimes there need to be several users for one data sorce (eg. one company).

Which license is the most appropriate for me and which would be for the users? Do they need an account with Salesforce or do I issue them an account? And how do the payments go - salesforce for account and to me for licensing an app.

The app need not be on the market for beginning.

Comment: I think you should develop an appexchange app then .

Comment: So I suppose, that then I need "One enterprise App" for  "Salesforce1 Platform" then, correct? How does it work for the user then? If the app is 20 €/month, what part do I get and what part goes to Salesforce? Does the user need to pay something extra or are these 20 € everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best advice to speak with an ISV partner manager to introduce you to all the requirement of releasing an app for your customers. Please see this [link](http://www.salesforce.com/partners/isv/) for more info. You have two main options: 
1. build an app in Force.com platform for non-salesforce customers, this is a low cost option however you will need to create all your own  objects from scratch - which may suits your needs.
2. build an app on the Salesforce.com platform and make use of the standard objects, however your customers will require salesforce licenses to utilise and install your app. You will need to build the app with a specific mimimum edition in mind too depending on what features you want to utilise in your app, such as workflows, custom page layouts etc.

Comment: I am assuming this isn't relevant for today?